# How to print all elements using python and selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python

I'm trying to make a code to get all the results from a specific search i do on a website.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to print all the results from the classes i need.

Here is my code:

```
#Silent Display Settings
display = Xvfb()
display.start()

#Login
url = "https://www.foo.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#Submit Form
if __name__ == "__main__":
   driver.get(url)
   select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('test-make-box'))
   select.select_by_value('Test')
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-primary.btn--search').click()
#Get info
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until( lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_class_name('listing-item__title'))
XYZ # Here output results
...


driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

Here I need to print all values that come from two classes called `listing-item__title` and `listing-item__price`, how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide the print output and the original css to complete this question/answer? It isn't possible to learn from this question in the current incomplete form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wait for both the elements having `listing-item__title` and `listing-item__price` classes and then locate elements via `.listing-item__title,.listing-item__price` *CSS selector* that would match both these types of elements:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'listing-item__title')))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'listing-item__price')))

for elm in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".listing-item__title,.listing-item__price"):
    print(elm.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much alecxe for your assistance. Now it works perfectly